# TigerVNC Xfce startup failing on new Debian 12 bookworm install. "Another session manager is already running" Worked on Debian 10

Tags: debian, xfce, tigervnc

I've set up a temporary Debian 12 instance on a laptop to test with prior to migrating a desktop from Debian 10 to 12.  The only thing not working so far is the tigervnc instance, but that's critical.

(Yes, this post is long, but I wanted to make sure that anyone viewing it had enough information to go off of, and to minimize the number of follow-up questions)

Several years ago I set up tigervnc-standalone-server on a Debian 10 amd64 system with Xfce4 desktop, and it's worked like a champ ever since.  Extremely stable, very responsive, etc.  However, it's time to move to Debian 12, and for the life of me, I can't get tigervnc to work on the Debian 12 test system that I've set up (installed using debian-12.2.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso)

### ***The existing Debian 10 configuration, which works fine (see further below for what isn't working):***

**Package version:**

```
Tigervnc-standalone-server 1.9.0+dfsg-3+deb10u3
```

**Config files:**

```
testuser@system:~$ cat ~/.vnc/xstartup
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
startxfce4
```

(the Xresources below is an empty file, so the xrdb line above probably doesn't do anything)

```
testuser@system:~$ cat ~/.Xresources
testuser@system:~$
```

(the geometry in the config file below is specified in the startup command, so the file below may not matter either)

```
testuser@system:~$ cat ~/.vnc/config
geometry=1920x1080
dpi=96
```

**Successful launch:**

```
testuser@system:~$ vncserver :1 -geometry 1920x1080 -localhost no

New 'system.org:1 (testuser)' desktop at :1 on machine system.org

Starting applications specified in /home/testuser/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/testuser/.vnc/system.org:1.log

Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth,TLSVnc -passwd /home/testuser/.vnc/passwd system.org:1 to connect to the VNC server.

testuser@system:~$
```

**Usage notes:**

If the Debian system is rebooted, I'll login to the testuser account using the kvm, open a terminal, and enter the command above.  I'll then logout of the KVM, and from that point on use VNC Viewer (RealVNC) on a Windows machine to connect to the Debian box.  After the initial Debian login, I can disconnect and re-connect the VNC client at will without having to logout of the Debian user's desktop (home environment, no port-forwarding, minimal security issues in doing so).  Works perfectly.  And yes, I know I could configure it to auto-start on boot, but I'd rather leave that part manual.

### ***The new Debian 12 configuration attempts, none of which work work:***

**Package version:**

```
tigervnc-standalone-server 1.12.0+dfsg-8
```

$ vncpasswd has been executed, and a password created for the same user which is issues the launch command.  When using VNC to start only /usr/bin/xterm, this password is accepted by the remote VNC viewer.

**Config files:**

```
~/.Xresources file: not present (wasn't needed before)
```

```
~/.vnc/config file: same as the Debian 10 file (defining geometry and dpi, but geometry is being overridden with the vncserver command)
```

```
~/.vnc/xstartup file: have tried multiple versions, none of which correctly start up an Xfce4 desktop on VNC.  See below for details.
```

Below are the different versions of ~/.vnc/xstartup which I've tried, with the corresponding output when attempting to startup the server:

1 Original, duplicating the Debian 10 file:

```
#!/bin/bash
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
startxfce4

Tailed log output from $ vncserver command:
=================== tail /home/sysuser/.vnc/testcase.nodomain.org:1.log ===================
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :1

(process:2353): xfce4-session-CRITICAL **: 02:42:27.394: dbus-launch not found, the desktop will not work properly!
xfce4-session-Message: 02:42:27.515: SSH authentication agent is already running
gpg-agent: a gpg-agent is already running - not starting a new one
===========================================================================================

Session startup via '/home/sysuser/.vnc/xstartup' cleanly exited too early (< 3 seconds)!
```

2 Without DBUS unset:

```
#!/bin/bash
unset SESSION_MANAGER
startxfce4

Tailed log output from $ vncserver command:
=================== tail /home/sysuser/.vnc/testcase.nodomain.org:1.log ===================
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :1
xfce4-session-Message: 01:46:16.716: SSH authentication agent is already running
gpg-agent: a gpg-agent is already running - not starting a new one
===========================================================================================

Session startup via '/home/sysuser/.vnc/xstartup' cleanly exited too early (< 3 seconds)!
```

3 Without any unsets:

```
#!/bin/bash
startxfce4

Tailed log output from $ vncserver command:
=================== tail /home/sysuser/.vnc/testcase.nodomain.org:1.log ===================
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :1
xfce4-session: Another session manager is already running
===========================================================================================

Session startup via '/home/sysuser/.vnc/xstartup' exited with status 1!
```

**Commonalities:**

In all cases, the outputs above are followed by this:

```
Maybe try something simple first, e.g.,
    tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/xterm
The X session exited with status 1!
Killing Xtigervnc process ID xxxx... success!
```

and when I do a $ vncserver -list command, it comes back with no instances running (header with nothing below).

**VNC's core is working:**

I know the VNC server is working at a base level, since if I reduce the xstartup file to nothing but:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/xterm
```

then, the $ vncserver -list command will show an X instance, I can connect to it from the Windows viewer, and a terminal window (but nothing else) is presented.  So it's just a matter of the Xfce4 not starting correctly.

Any ideas??

Comment: You may try looking for an X directory in temp, deleting it and running the script, killing X instances, disable session manager from init, and what about running vnc command over ssh, skipping the script files? Also you may use x11vnc to see what is actually served on display 1.

Comment: @AbdullahIbnFulan apparently the X server running line given is just a harmless message from the startxfce4 script. It is not an error / related to the real problem.

Comment: Btw, have you checked the system journal to see if xfce4-session has segfault'd or so? There seems to be no real error given except `cleanly exited too early`.

Comment: @TomYan The only messages I am seeing in the system journal are related to the gpg-agent.service.  Those messages are only generated if I configure the unset SESSION MANAGER line in the xstartup config file.  They seem to be status messages, not errors.  To check, I added groups adm and systemd-journal to my user (to see all messages), ran journalctl -f in one window, and executed the vncserver command above in another window.  No activity in the journalctl window other than those noted.

Comment: @AbdullahIbnFulan Thanks, but I ll'd /tmp and found no directory related to tigervnc or X11.  That and the vncserver /list being empty both indicate there is no X server actively running when I issue my startup command.

Comment: Have you tried it manually over ssh instead of relying on script?

Comment: @AbdullahIbnFulan I'm not certain that I fully understand your question.  I am not tunneling this connection using SSH, and I am issuing the command directly from a local terminal window on the laptop in the Xfce desktop.  If the script you're referring to is /usr/bin/vncserver, I believe it calls Xtigervnc.  I tried running Xtigervnc with the same arguments as vncserver.  It did not seem to give an error, but when executing vncserver -list, no active sessions were presented.  However, when I attempted to connect from the viewer, it did attempt a connection, but the password was not accepted.